# Configure Memcached with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, memcached, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having problems trying to use Memcached in a Rails 3 Application ...

My question is quite simple : **How I'm supposed to configure Memcached to make it works with Rails 3 ?**

Thanks for your help !

Edit:

It looks like the object isn't correctly deserialized by the `Rails.cache.read` no matter `:raw => true` or `:raw => false` but the deserialization is working if it's done just after the `Rails.cache.write`

Comment: What is it exactly your problems? You need to be specific. Please elaborate it here so we can help you.

Comment: @jpartogi : I found the solution by my self. It wasn't a configuration error but the symptoms were making me thinking it was. I'll post a response with an explanation. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so,

Complete context :

The serialized object had his Class into a Lib files. The lib files are auto loaded by rails using using the standard naming convention.
The `Rails.cache.read` was the first step of any actions in my application (except the init action which creates the object for the first time).
So, i had an error on any other action : `undefined method for String`. This was because the `Rails.cache.read` was returning me a String (serialized object) instead of my object instance.

Explanation :

It looks like Marshal doesn't use the Rails system to find Undeclared constants. So, when i was calling `Rails.cache.read` the `Marshal.load` was falling and `read` was returning the `String` without throwing any error.

The Solution :

I simply added a `load` of my lib in my application controller. That way, all the constants are already loaded when `Rails.cache.read` calls `Marshal.load`
Note that i used `load` instead of `require` in development mode to avoid to have to restart my server after each modification.

Hopefully this will help someone.